# Is there any way to keep the original Id when migrating using Azure DevOps Migration Tools?

Tags: azure, azure-devops-migration-tools, azure-migrate

I'm using the Azure DevOps Migration Tools to migrate our work items from one organisation to another.

The ReflectedWorkItemIDFieldName fills in ID_old with values like https://dev.azure.com/myOldSite/MyProject/_workitems/edit/99

I'd like to be able to migrate Id=xx from myOldSite to Id=xx from myNewSite, but I'm not able to find a way to migrate the Id number from the old to the new Azure DevOps systems.

Any thoughts?

My configuration.json is

```
{
  "Version": "8.9",
  "TelemetryEnableTrace": false,
  "workaroundForQuerySOAPBugEnabled": false,
  "Source": {
    "Collection": "https://dev.azure.com/myOldSite/",
    "Project": "MyProject",
    "ReflectedWorkItemIDFieldName": "Id",
    "AllowCrossProjectLinking": false,
    "PersonalAccessToken": ""
  },
  "Target": {
    "Collection": "https://dev.azure.com/myNewSite/",
    "Project": "MyProject",
    "ReflectedWorkItemIDFieldName": "Custom.ID_old",
    "AllowCrossProjectLinking": false,
    "PersonalAccessToken": ""
  },
  "FieldMaps": [],
  "WorkItemTypeDefinition": {
    "sourceWorkItemTypeName": "targetWorkItemTypeName"
  },
  "GitRepoMapping": null,
  "Processors": [
    {
      "ObjectType": "VstsSyncMigrator.Engine.Configuration.Processing.NodeStructuresMigrationConfig",
      "PrefixProjectToNodes": false,
      "Enabled": true,
      "BasePaths": []
    },
    {
      "ObjectType": "VstsSyncMigrator.Engine.Configuration.Processing.WorkItemMigrationConfig",
      "ReplayRevisions": false,
      "PrefixProjectToNodes": false,
      "UpdateCreatedDate": true,
      "UpdateCreatedBy": true,
      "UpdateSourceReflectedId": false,
      "BuildFieldTable": false,
      "AppendMigrationToolSignatureFooter": false,
      "QueryBit": "AND [System.WorkItemType] NOT IN ('Test Suite', 'Test Plan')",
      "OrderBit": "[System.ChangedDate] desc",
      "Enabled": true,
      "LinkMigration": true,
      "AttachmentMigration": true,
      "AttachmentWorkingPath": "c:\\temp\\WorkItemAttachmentWorkingFolder\\",
      "FixHtmlAttachmentLinks": false,
      "SkipToFinalRevisedWorkItemType": false,
      "WorkItemCreateRetryLimit": 5,
      "FilterWorkItemsThatAlreadyExistInTarget": true,
      "PauseAfterEachWorkItem": false,
      "AttachmentMazSize": 480000000,
      "CollapseRevisions": false
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The ID is system-generated and can't be guaranteed to not already be used by a different work item in the target system.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I expected as much, but just wanted to ask the question. I'll mark this as answered, as it is as good as it can get!